# Let $\mathbf{A}=\mathbf{\hat{Q}\hat{R}}$. Prove that $\mathbf{Ax}=0 \iff \mathbf{Rx}=0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $\mathbf{A}=\mathbf{\hat{Q}\hat{R}}$, where $\mathbf{\hat{Q}\hat{R}}$ is the reduced QR factorization of $\mathbf{A}$. Prove that $\mathbf{Ax}=0 \iff \mathbf{\hat{R}x}=0$

Intuitively, I know that is true because recalling the Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization algorithm, $\mathbf{\hat{R}}$ contains the scale factors of $\mathbf{\hat{Q}}$ that make up $\mathbf{A}$, so if $\mathbf{\hat{R}x}\neq0$ then $\mathbf{\hat{Q}\hat{R}x}\neq0$.

So how do I show that the null space of $\mathbf{A}$ is equivalent to the null space of $\mathbf{\hat{R}}$?

EDIT : $\mathbf{A}$ is a m by n matrix where m $\ge$ n.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition, $\mathbf{Q}$ contains an orthonormal basis, hence, it has no null space. It follows that there is no $\mathbf{z}\neq\mathbf{0}$ such that $\mathbf{Qz}=\mathbf{0}$; $\mathbf{Qz}=\mathbf{0}$ if and only if for $\mathbf{z}=\mathbf{0}$. Now take $\mathbf{z}=\mathbf{Rx}$.

For the reduced QR-decomposition you would get
$$ \mathbf{A}=\mathbf{QR}=[\mathbf{Q}_1,\ \mathbf{Q}_2][\mathbf{R}_1,\ \mathbf{0}]^T=\mathbf{Q}_1 \mathbf{R}_1.$$
But note that $\mathbf{R}_1\mathbf{x}=[\mathbf{z},\ \mathbf{0}]^T$, and the result still holds.

Comment: Would you kindly elaborate why if $\mathbf{\hat{Q}}$ has an orthonormal basis then its null space only contains the zero vector? Also just thought I'd clarify that $\mathbf{\hat{Q}}$ may not be a square matrix.

Comment: If the square matrix $\mathbf{Q}$ is orthogonal, it has full rank. Hence, by the rank-nullity theorem, the dimension of its null space is zero (i.e., the point $\mathbf{0}$).